# Как сделать всплывающее окно при нажатии на правую кнопку мыши?

Tags: java, javafx, всплывающее-окно, мышь

Нужно сделать, что-бы при нажатии правой кнопки мыши в области TableView всплывало окно, где пользователь мог бы выбрать, что ему сделать (скопировать, удалить ячейку т.д. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Menu 1");
cm.getItems().add(mi1);
MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem("Menu 2");
cm.getItems().add(mi2);

table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if(t.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            cm.show(table, t.getScreenX(), t.getScreenY());
        }
    }
});
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009377/context-menu-on-a-row-of-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать RequestContext для запуска js-кода внутри вашего управляемого компонента. jsf+ ajax.